# How can I perform onClickListener on two object using interface in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have a Fragment class which extends `View.onClickListener` and I have implement *@overriden* method i.e **onClick**.
I have 2 `imageView` which performs `onClickListener`.

1. `filterIcon.setOnClickListener(this)`
2. `fab.setOnClickListener(this)`

And set both activities in *@overriden* method i.e. **`onClick()`**.

I want to know can this is possible that `onClickListener` will call the related `clickEvent`? If yes, how? If not, why?

Here's my code :

```
public class ExpenseFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView totalExpenseTV;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ImageView filterIcon;
    private PieChart pieChart;

    private Animation rotateForward, rotateBackward;

    private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ExpenseModel> options;
    private MyAdapter adapter;

    private int calendarImgClick = 0;
    private int groceryClick = 0;
    private int bikeClick = 0;
    private int rentClick = 0;
    private int foodsClick = 0;
    private int beerClick = 0;
    private int setCalClick = 0;

    private String whichCategorySelected = "";
    private String selectedDate;

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View attachInParentView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(attachInParentView, savedInstanceState);
        findViewByIDS(attachInParentView);
        setupRecyclerView();
        fabAnimation();
        fab.setOnClickListener(this);
        filterIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
        databaseListener();


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_expense, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        fab.startAnimation(rotateForward);
        rotateForward.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                addNote();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        filterIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.filter_off);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.filterIcon) {
        // codul care se executează când este apăsată imaginea filterIcon
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.fab) {
        // codul care se executează când este apăsată imaginea fab
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this using Kotlin:

```kotlin
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    when (view.getId) {
        R.id.filterIcon -> {
            //do something
        }

        R.id.fab -> {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is "when" is a keyword in java ?? i don't think so

Comment: yes, this is the keyword

Comment: I did not found "when" keyboard in java

Comment: @prabinchand This syntax comes from another JVM language, - Kotlin(https://kotlinlang.org/)

Comment: yes , this is kotlin